# WebStorm debug using localhost after adding deployment config?

Tags: webstorm

By default in WebStorm if you hit "Run" or use the browser hover selection, it will launch the html file using `http://localhost:????`.  I have added a test webserver `http://test.mydomain.com` to the deployment configs.

How can I now debug locally again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you like to have your pages hosted on `http://localhost:63342` by default despite having `http://test.mydomain.com` set up as a deployment server?

When you are using `Open in browser` action, or preview a file in browser using browsers bar in editor, or create a new Run/Debug configuration from `.html` file right-click menu, WebStorm uses URL from current Deployment entry (which is marked as **Default**) to build full URL. If you have no deployment entries defined, then built-in web server (`http://localhost:63342`) is used.

There is a feature request to optionally use built-in webserver for previewing files in browser regardless of deployment settings, [WEB-18958](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-18958).

For now, I can suggest the following workarounds:

1. Make your deployment entry non-default (right-click, `Stop using as default`)
   Note that it will break auto-deployment (if you have it set up)

[image]

2. or, use **Run configuration** with the built-in server URL for running your application. But, as run configurations created from right-click menu always have the default server URL pre-configured, you need to edit created configurations in `Run | Edit configurations...` dialog, making sure that the built-in sderver URL is specified there instead of your deployment server URL.

Comment: "Stop using as default" works great for now, thanks. I'll check out the YT issue.